# I'm positive this is another Riley riddle

Tags: riddle

> My prefix is good; I'm skilled in my field.
>   My infix is nonsense; I fall to pieces.
>   My suffix is the massive weight of a hundred darts.
>   All in all, I am minuscule, yet present everywhere.

What am I?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you are a

> Proton

My prefix is good; I'm skilled in my field.

> *Pro*, which means a favourable argument but is also short for professional.

My infix is nonsense; I fall to pieces.

> *Rot*, the nonsense part refers to a rot cipher, I think.

My suffix is the massive weight of a hundred darts.

> *Ton*, a one hundred in darts is usually called a ton.

All in all, I am minuscule, yet present everywhere.

> Protons are tiny and present everywhere

I'm positive

> Positively charged

Comment: Well, *that* was fast.
Did the "hundred darts" make it too obvious?

Comment: I can't answer for hexomino, but for me at least, the "massive weight" part was what gave it away. You could have said "feathers" instead of "hundred darts" and I still think the hint would have been equally effective, if initially a bit misleading.

Comment: I was trying to clue each segment twice in each line.
So, for the infix, "nonsense" is another cluing (similar to "rubbish", in spoken vernacular).
"Hundred darts" is required for the second cluing; substituting "feathers" loses that conceit.